# Can not install pip on my Ubuntu 9.04 via apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, pip, apt-get, ubuntu-9.04

I cannot install pip via apt-get, is that because the system is too old? I tried to change sources but it doesn't work.

Comment: Anything older than 14.04 is EOL.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install with [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run

```
python get-pip.py
```